# Calculating gain ratio from a dB value

Tags: logarithms, mathematical-physics

In a practice problem I have:

power gain = $\log_{10}(\frac{db}{20})$

The final answer for the ratio is 1. The dB value is $-3$.

When I do $\log_{10}(\frac{3}{20})$ I get $-0.823$.

Just wondering if someone can shed some light on what I am doing wrong.